# What causes the "route not defined" error in this Laravel 8 API?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a registration form with **Laravel 8** and Angular 13. The back-end is an [API](https://github.com/Ajax30/larachat) (link to Github repo). In the UserController I have a `signin()` and a `signout()` method

**UserController**

```
public function signin(Request $request)
{
    $fields = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    // Check email
    $user = User::where('email', $fields['email'])->first();

    // Check password
    if (!$user || !Hash::check($fields['password'], $user->password)) {
        return response(['message' => 'Incorrect email and/or password'], 401);
    }

    $token = $user->createToken('secret-token')->plainTextToken;

    $response = [
        'user' => $user,
        'token' => $token
    ];

    return response($response, 201);
}

public function signout(Request $request)
{
    auth()->user()->tokens->each(function ($token) {
        $token->delete();
    });

    return [
        'message' => 'You have been signed out.'
    ];
}
```

**routes\api.php**

```
Route::post('/signup', [UserController::class, 'signup']);
Route::post('/signin', [UserController::class, 'signin']);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
    Route::post('/signout', [UserController::class, 'signout']);
});
```

#### The problem

I get the error when I access `https://mysite.test/api/signout` in Postman.

> Route [login] not defined.

##### Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `App\Http\Kernel.php`

Replace

```php
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
...
```

with

```php
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
...
```

But that alone is not gonna cut it.

In your `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`

add this method to the class

```php
    protected function unauthenticated($request, \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);
    }
```

The reasoning is behind how Laravel detects if the request [`shouldReturnJson`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L408) when handling an `AuthenticationException`.

You indicate you want json response by sending
`Accept: application/json` (not `Accept */*`) request header.

Here's your scenario:

Your `signout` route is behind `auth` middleware.
You're detected as guest (probably you're not sending the auth headers correctly?) and you don't want json response (the missing json Accept header). At this point Laravel redirects you to `login` by [default](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php#L17).

Comment: There is no `unauthenticated` method in my `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`. I use Laravel version 8.83.10.

Comment: You have to override it from the parent. It's not there by default. @RazvanZamfir

Comment: Ok, I did all the above. Now when I log out, the response is not _You have been signed out_, but `{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}`.

Comment: Fair enough. It's the auth middleware stopping you now. You need to make sure you're sending the right auth headers. Namely, `Authorization: Bearer <your-token>`

Answer (score 2):

In headers(postman), add following key value

**Accept : application/json**

Comment: I have `Accept */*`.

Answer (score 1):

Its hitting the Authenticate Middleware where by default it redirects you to route('login'). This is because when you delete the token the user doesn't have access through auth:sanctum so it redirects the Unauthenticated user to the login route that doesn't exists. Just change the redirect in Middleware/Authenticate to signin/signout route.

Change the singout() in your Controller to this

```
Auth::guard($this->guard())->logout();

Request::session()->invalidate();

Request::session()->regenerateToken();
```

This will logout the user without hitting the Authenticate Middleware, it will return a json response of 204 or No Content. NOTE: just change your set guard instead of `$this->guard()` I recommend adding a private function inside of your UserController so you can get the correct guard every time and that would look like this

```
if(isset($this->guard) && $this->guard) {
    return $this->guard;
}

return config('auth.defaults.guard');
```

Comment: I get `Route [api.signup] not defined`

Comment: Has this solved your problem?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

in laravel 8 after modify route file (or config files) you must use
`php artisan optimize` command